# NumPad Not Working in Windows 10 VM on VMware Player with Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I'm currently facing an issue with VMware Player on my Windows 11 laptop.
I've installed a Windows 10 virtual machine, but I've noticed that the number keypad (NumPad) on my Bluetooth keyboard does not work inside the VM. The rest of the keyboard functions correctly, both in the host OS and within the VM, but the NumPad specifically does not respond at all when I'm working inside the Windows 10 VM.

I've already installed vmware-tools on my windows 10 VM machine. Also, I have searched and tried several ways with no luck.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off topic on Stack Overflow. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: In the link you provided, it contains `software tools commonly used by programmers`. VMWare isn't a tool that many develoers commonly use? If my question is not a proper one on here, why does stackoverflow have those tags which i was able to add?

Comment: It means tools that are primarily used by programmers. Also please read the description under [tag:vmware] Existence of tag does not mean question is on topic. Windows tag obviously exists for questions related to Windows programming, but general Windows usage questions are off topic. Same goes for VMvare.

Comment: Hey, i can't close nor delete my post since it has an open bounty. The bounty will expire in 7 days, so i will close this by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring various solutions and ensuring VMware Tools was installed in my Windows 10 VM, I finally discovered a simple yet effective fix for this problem.

The solution was to press the NumLock key on my laptop's built-in keyboard (instead of Bluetooth keyboard) after starting the VM. This action enabled the NumPad functionality on the Bluetooth keyboard as well within the virtual machine.

It appears there might be a mechanism within VMware and the Windows 10 VM environment that requires the NumLock state to be toggled from the host's physical keyboard to properly recognize the NumPad input from a Bluetooth keyboard.

I hope this solution helps anyone facing a similar issue with NumPad functionality in a VMware virtual environment.